# Is there a way to make hibernate recognize as a new entity an entity with ID != null?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'll start by explaining my objective:
I have to update a very complex entity and the altered entity comes from an external source so it is an unmanaged entity and any merge() on it would fail.

My idea would be to simply perform a delete followed by an insert:

```
@Transactional
public class MyClass{
 ....
public void updateEntity(Entity newEntity){ //altered entity, newly created
     Entity oldEntity = dao.findById(newEntity.getId()); //retrieves managed entity object
     dao.delete(oldEntity); //deletes it
     dao.insert(newEntity); //calls EntityManager.persist()
```

Anyway the insert() throws me the following:

```
Detached entity passed to persist
```

In order to solve that I would have to nullify the ID so that hibernate recognizes it as a new entity, anyway I want to keep the old ID to keep trace of the update.

The ID is currently autogenerated so it seems hibernate will recognize any entity with ID!=null as an already existing entry inside of the underlying table and so will throw that exception.
Isn't there a way to prevent that?

Comment: First of all, that's clearly not the real error message you get. You probably get "Detached entity passed to persist". And that isn't caused by the delete being delayed. It's caused by the fact that you're passing a detached entity (i.e. an entity that already has a generated ID or version) to persist().

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited. So, hibernate will recognize any entity with an ID != null as an entry into the db?

Comment: If this ID is autogenerated, yes.

Comment: Mmm..and isn't there a way to tell hibernate to not do that? By doing this transaction I am 100% sure that the ID is not present into the DB (it, indeed, belong to this same entity). Edited the post btw, thanks for your help

Comment: AFAIK, the only way is to make the ID not autogenerated.